# How to remove the key in array an want to save in a string

Tags: php, jquery, html

My Html

```
    <input type="textbox" name="bus[]" value="">
    <input type="textbox" name="bus[]" value="">
    <input type="textbox" name="bus[]" value="">
    <input type="textbox" name="bus[]" value="">
```

MY Script

```
$busac = $_post[bus];
$busaccount = count($busac);
    if($busaccount != 0){
    for($bc=0;$bc<$busaccount;$bc++){
        $acbusmodel[]=array('bus'=>array('busmodel'=>array('local'=>$busrsac[$bc],'others'=>$busdollar[$bc])));
    } // endforeach
    }

foreach($acbusmodel as $key=>$value) {
            $values[$key] = $value;
            $acvalue .= $value;
            print_r($value);
        }
Array ( [0] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) ) )
```

Above is the display code

i want code like this

```
Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) )
```

i want to save the value in single string..

Comment: Arrays can't work as you desired.

Comment: You want to save this value: `Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) )` in a single string???

Comment: why do you want to 'save' an array in a string? are you trying to serialize in a specific format?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is what you need

replace `print_r($value)`

with

```
$c = count($value);
$fin='';
for($ i =0;$i<$c;$i++)
{

    $fin .=print_r($value[i],true); // this will print to variable (not on browser)

}
```

Comment: pls check i want the loop array in a string

Comment: i think u didnt understand my question

Comment: @faizphp is this `Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) )` the desired o/p? if not what?

Comment: did u check that one <pre>$acvalue .= $value;</pre> i put like this i called but it shows single array

Comment: @simpleuser `print_r ` will directly print the data on browser.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar if you dont give the second argument `true` you are right. if you give `true` it will print to variable. Please refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: @faizphp just to make sure. Its currenly printing `Array ( [0] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) ) )` this right?

Answer (score 0):

make another array using the previous array

```
$newarray = $oldarray[0];
```

Comment: no i dont want like this one Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 1 [others] => 1 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 2 [others] => 2 ) ) ) Array ( [bus] => Array ( [busmodel] => Array ( [local] => 3 [others] => 3 ) ) ) this total array i want in string out in for loop

Comment: @faizphp : his code'll remove the 1st index i.e. [0] and 'll o/p only the remaining part that you want... But it'll again be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace print_r($value); with following code

```
 $new_value=array();
  foreach($value as $data){
    array_push($new_value, $data);
  }
 $value=$new_value;
 print_r($value);
```